# Let $\mathbb{Z}^n,\mathbb{Z}^m$ be a free abelian group, $m<n.$ Prove $\mathbb{Z}^n \not\cong \mathbb{Z}^m$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

Let $\mathbb{Z}^n,\mathbb{Z}^m$ be a free abelian group, $m<n.$

Prove $\mathbb{Z}^n \not\cong \mathbb{Z}^m$

Is it possible that the problem is trivial since $\mathbb{Z}^n$ has $n$ generators and  $\mathbb{Z}^m$ has $m$ generators ,$n\neq m$ ,hence $\mathbb{Z}^n\not\cong\mathbb{Z}^m$?

Comment: How do you know $\mathbb{Z}^n$ doesn't have $m$ generators?  A group typically has many different generating sets.

Comment: Besides having an $n$-element generating set, $\mathbb Z^n$ also has an $n+1$ element generating set. For instance, $\mathbb Z^1=\mathbb Z$ has a $2$ element generating set $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Tensor with $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: The typical proof is tensoring with a field.

Comment: Based on the OP's other questions I would guess that this question is for someone in an intro to abstract algebra class, where they would not learn about tensor products. I believe the "correct" proof at this level is using the [fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group), often (?) taught in intro abstract algebra without proof.

Comment: You can also kill $2x$ for every $x$ in the group, and compare what you get.